# When should I use numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a newbee of python. And recently I heard some people say that numpy is a good module for dealing with huge data.

I'm curious what can numpy do for us in the daily work.

As I know, most of us were not scientists and researchers, at what circumstances numpy can bring us benefit?

Can you share a good practice with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer short, when you need do huge mathematical operations, like vector multiplications and so on which requires writing lots of loops and what not, yet your codes gets unreadable yet not efficient you should use Numpy.

Few key benefits:

- NumPy arrays have a fixed size at creation, unlike Python lists (which can grow dynamically). Changing the size of an ndarray will create a new array and delete the original. So it is more memory efficient than the other.
- The elements in a NumPy array are all required to be of the same data type, and thus will be the same size in memory. The exception: one can have arrays of (Python, including NumPy) objects, thereby allowing for arrays of different sized elements.
- NumPy arrays facilitate advanced mathematical and other types of operations on large numbers of data. Typically, such operations are executed more efficiently and with less code than is possible using Python’s built-in sequences.
- A growing plethora of scientific and mathematical Python-based packages are using NumPy arrays; though these typically support Python-sequence input, they convert such input to NumPy arrays prior to processing, and they often output NumPy arrays. In other words, in order to efficiently use much (perhaps even most) of today’s scientific/mathematical Python-based software, just knowing how to use Python’s built-in sequence types is insufficient - one also needs to know how to use NumPy arrays.
  -Vector operations comes handy in Numpy. You don't need to go through writing loops but yet pythonic.
  -Object oriented approach

Comment: I don't see how the first point is a benefit.

Comment: Well, static and dynamic array size has its own benefits, right? It depends on requirements. Sometimes one is better than other.

Comment: @larsmans - A better way to state the first point is that numpy arrays are much more memory efficient than containers such as lists because the values are simply stored as an array, rather than a sequence of pointers.

Comment: @JoeKington: sure, but that has nothing to do with growing dynamically. It's not even true: `ndarray.resize` will resize a NumPy array under the right circumstances. The reason that resizing doesn't always work is that NumPy arrays allow views.